# how use vars created in the with_elements and used in a with_subelement loop

Tags: ansible

I want to include tasks and create users with the item var created by the with_items function

It's a part of a big code. I can't post here the entire code but i need to create a user by multiple way and very different way.

in my create.yml i make differents tests to choose the good file to include. In this exemple i's because the type of the user is "simple" so i include the create_simple.yml file

For exemple :

file create.yml :

```
- name: 'Create'
  include_tasks: create_simple.yml user='{{ item }}'
  with_items: 
    - '{{ userslist }}'
  when: item.simple
```

Here a exemple of the userslist :

```
userslist:
  - name: 'user1'
    simple: False
    uid: '1002'
    password: 'test'
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    comment: 'comment user1'
    primary: 'groupe1'
    gid: '30002'
    groups:
      - gname: 'secondary'
        gid: 30000
    remote_groups:
       - gname: 'remote'
    expires: 1580472000
    generate_ssh_key: true
    ssh_key_type: 'rsa'
  - name: 'test'
    simple: True
    uid: '1002'
    password: 'test'
    shell: '/bin/bash'
    comment: 'test'
    gid: '30003'
    groups:
      - gname: 'test'
        gid: 30000
    expires: 1580472000
    generate_ssh_key: true
    ssh_key_type: 'rsa'
```

in the create_simple.yml file i have this :

```
- name: 'test'
  debug: msg='{{ resultat.1.gname }}'
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ lookup('dict', user) }}"
    - groups
  loop_control:
    loop_var: resultat
```

But i have this message :

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: with_dict expects a dict"}
```

the user var in the with_items of the create.yml file seem to be a dict
I have test to convert the user var in a dict but it doesn't work.

Comment: `seem to be a dict` => seeming is not enough. It **must be**. What makes you think it is a dict ? Show us. Moreover: 1) rather than playing around passing `item` to `user`, why don't you directly change the `loop_var` to `user` ? 2) you don't need to declare `with_items` as a list of list `with_items: "{{ userslist }}"` is enough.

Comment: I have the feeling that all of this can be done in a single task. Can you show the structure of `userslist` ?

Comment: I pass the item to user when i do the include because i'm thinking the item was not accessible in the include_task to do an another loop in this item to ge all of groups for exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_subelements` requires a [list of hashes (i.e. dictionaries) and a key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) to lookup in each element on this list, but the list of hashes returned by `lookup('dict', user)` will return something like:

```
[ 
  {
    "key": "comment", 
    "value": "comment user1"
  }, 
  {
    "key": "shell", 
    "value": "/bin/bash"
  }, 
  {
    "key": "name", 
    "value": "user1"
  }
  ...
]
```

And `with_subelements` will try to find key `groups` in each of the dictionary in this list, which fails.

```
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ lookup('dict', user) }}" # Wrong: items in this list of dict does not have 'groups' keys
    - groups # OK: this a field name to lookup
```

In included `create_simple.yml`, the variable `user` will be a dictionary such as:

```
name: 'user1'
simple: False
groups:
  - gname: 'secondary'
    gid: 30000
...
```

If you want to list `groups` each time `create_simple.yml` is included, you can do in `create_simple.yml`:

```
- name: 'test'
  debug: 
    msg: '{{ resultat.gname }}'
  with_items: "{{ user.groups }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: resultat
```

Or even simpler if you only need a single task in `create_simple.yml`, you can use directly `with_subelements` instead of `include_tasks` in `create.yml`:

```
# this will lookup field 'groups' in each element of the 'userslist' variable
- name: 'Create'
  debug:
    msg: "Group for user {{ resultat.0.name }}: {{ resultat.1.gname }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ userslist }}"
    - groups  
  loop_control:
    loop_var: resultat
```